# How can I execute a callback after all AJAX requests in a loop finish?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

I have a loop which iterates through an array of HTML elements. Each iteration makes a GET request (the url of which depends on the current element) and does some additional processing. If I wanted to signal that all requests have completed, how would I do so?

The HTML elements are of the format

```
<td align="left">Item name</td>
```

Here's what I have:

```
var url = "http://example.com/page.phtml?item=";
var items = $(itemList).find('table tbody tr td[align=left]');
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    (function (i) {
        var itemName = items[i].innerHTML;
        $.get(url + itemName, function(data) {
            // process some stuff
            console.log("Processing item " + itemName);
        });
    })(i);
}
```

As you can see, the function which makes the GET call is in a closure. After all of the requests have completed, how can I use a callback like `console.log("DONE")`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `$.when()`:

```
var url = "http://example.com/page.phtml?item=";
var items = $(itemList).find('table tbody tr td[align=left]');
var promises = items.map(function(i, elem) {
    var itemName = items[i].innerHTML;
    return $.get(url + itemName, function(data) {
        // process some stuff
        console.log("Processing item " + itemName);
    });
}).get();
$.when.apply($, promises).done(function() {
    // all promises done here
});
```

You accumulate an array of promises (which is what is returned from `$.get()`) and then pass that array of promises to `$.when()` and it creates a summary promise that is resolved when all the other promises are resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options. 
The simple method is to keep count in the callback handler and then only execute your follow up code after the number of callbacks js equal to your number of items in the array.

The more expensive but valuable is to use promises. There are plenty of libs out there for using promises. If you decide to go this route I suggest looking for a .all or.when functiin that can handle an array of promises.

Comment: [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d4vfzbxw/) that demonstrates your first option.